# Visual Studio - Connection String for SQL Server Database Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, visual-studio-2017

What is the correct way to write a connection string for a SQL Server Database Project within the same solution?

My connection string defaults as

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-PokemonDayCare-20170701121228.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-PokemonDayCare-20170701121228;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

That LocalDB doesn't actually exist, so it creates it once it needs it (I think it does because I'm using single user authentication?).

So I need to make sure it doesn't create another database if I get the connection string wrong.

Here are the properties for my database project (it sits in the same solution as my web app).

[image: Project Properties]

- **How do I create a connection string for the database project?**

(sorry if it's stupid or painfully obvious)

Answer (score 4):

- In your solution explorer double click properties
- Select the Debug Tab
- Select Edit Under Target Connection String Setting

Comment: That provides a list of recent connection, but it does not display the existing connection information.